# ¿Por qué SAPUI5 no es una etiqueta de Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

No encuentro etiquetas de [sapui5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5) o [ui5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui5), como las hay de [js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/js) o [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). ¿Es por el volumen de consultas? ¿O de qué depende?

Comment: Basicamente porque no hay preguntas que las hayan necesitado.

Answer (score 2):

Una etiqueta aparece en la lista de etiquetas si:

1. Está en una pregunta activa.
2. Es un sinónimo a otra etiqueta activa.

Tan pronto como una etiqueta se usa en una pregunta, aparece en la lista de etiquetas. Si la etiqueta se elimina de la pregunta, seguirá apareciendo temporalmente, pero hay un proceso automático que borra esas "etiquetas huérfanas" (si no me equivoco corre a media noche.)

Respondiendo a tu pregunta: ¿por qué no existen las etiquetas `SAPUI5` o `UI5`? Porque no hay ninguna pregunta que las tenga. Tan pronto como las uses, aparecerán en la lista de etiquetas.

**Si por algún motivo no puedes agregar nuevas etiquetas** a tu pregunta (necesitas 300 puntos para poder crear etiquetas), dinos qué pregunta las necesita y nosotros las podemos añadir por ti.